# How can I call Javascript inside formsweb.cfg?

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracleforms, database-administration

In the [Changing the Browser title](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=490429) I read that it is possible to **dynamically** change the "pageTitle" of the "formsweb.cfg" with the help of Javascript.

My aim is to **dynamically** show the name of the oracle forms (10g) in the browsers page title. How can I use a function like this

```
# HTML page title
  <script>
     function setWindowTitle(x)
       {
         document.title=x;
       }
     </script>
    setWindowTitle(form);
```

in my formsweb.cfg to return the form name and set it in the browser title?!!!!

Does anybody know how I can do it?

I appreciate any kind of help

Answer (score 1):

You can change your title in the base.htm file or whatever you're using as a file.
Here you can also use javascript because it is a normal html file.

For the title depending on data or so you can use cookies.
You can create it from triggers and you can also read it with javascript.

Answer (score -1):

You can see some examples of manipulating the applet browser window dynamically here:

http://oracleformsinfo.wordpress.com/2011/12/25/getting-the-browser-window-under-control-when-separateframetrue/

If you would like to pass parameters from the Forms itself such as the Form name you must be using Forms 11g and use javascript to send the Form name to the page itself.

For a solution in Forms 4.5 - 10g you can set the Form window title very easily to be the Form name using get_application_property to get the form name and then set_window_property to set the Form window title.

Comment: set_window_property('frm_mdi_window', title, get_application_property(CURRENT_FORM_NAME));  in pre-form or when-new-form instance, does not work. I want to change the title of my broweser so that instead of "Oracle Application Server Form services- Windows Internet Explorer" I can see "the name of my form".